# How do I remove USB's plastic fragments from the USB port?

Tags: technology, plastics

The plastic of my USB thumbdrive had cracked and the one of the fragments was stuck inside the USB port. How can I remove it **without damaging** my USB port?

[image: picture of the broken flash drive; the plastic casing that should cover the metal ribbons has snapped off unevenly]

Comment: Somebody to explain why you are closing this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a pair of thin [tweezers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FFYMYU), like these:

[image]

Comment: @Shoket , yes I tried it but it seems to be stuck quite tightly, and I am afraid to damage USB port itself. Should I bring it to the Sony Centre?

Comment: Hm....I dunno. If it still works, then I guess you could keep using it, though I would recommend backing up all the data that's on it, as soon as you can. I have no idea how Sony works with broken devices.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have already accepted an answer, but I wanted to add something that might prove useful for other users who might not have tweezers or such things.

- ***Blu Tack.*** - That's all I really have to say on the situation, get a nice big bit of Blu Tack and press it on the area you want to remove the broken bits from (push fairly hard in order to get it really in there) and then just pull off the afflicted area and it should, depending how wedged the bits are, bring out all the bits.
  I find Blu Tack so useful for picking up small items and cleaning the odd dusty area - it wouldn't cause any damage to the USB port as there aren't any hard or pointy elements to it that could potentially damage the port. The only possible problem it could present is that you would get Blu Tack stuck in the  port as well as the existing mess. **BUT GUESS WHAT**: Blu Tack will be able to get that stubborn Blue Tack out - a few quick presses and releases of the Blu Tack should see you Tack free in no time!

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: @elliodawes .. Thanks for sharing but I think that Blu Tack is too weak to remove the fragment though it will not damage the port.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little riskier than Blu Tack, but what about something like acrylic caulk, which will shrink and grip the fragment as it cures?  You can make a "handle" out of the caulk after filling the port.

I would advise experimenting and testing the tensile strength of the cured caulk *outside* of the port first.

Comment: Does this provide any benefit over tweezers?